# Installing Outlook Add-In

Tags: windows-7, add-in, outlook-2007, setup-project, outlook-addin

I have a problem. I've been installing my VSTO Outlook Add-In to the Outlook 2007 on the account that has no security limitations. For the setup, I am using a normal visual studio setup project. I've had the user install few versions of my application before and it worked fine. Recently, I've created a new version of my application (which is installed to HKLM and to HKCU registry ([hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976811) that allows me to install the add-in to HKLM registry was also installed)). Now the outlook add-in doesn't even load on the user's computer. If you look in Outlook/Trust Center/Add-ins/ you will see my outlook add-in showing up under "Inactive Application Add-ins", but when I try to enable it, I get a message "This add-in is installed for all users on this computer, and can only be connected or disconnected by an administrator" even though I am logged in as administrator. I also looked in the registry and it has LoadBehaviour as 3, which means that it should appear under active add-ins. I tried installing old version, but now it also doesn't work and does not even appear as installed Outlook add-in.
What can be a cause of this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spent a week on finding a solution and it was so damn simple... the problem was that I've set identical registry settings to HKCU registry and HKLM registry. As a result the registry settings were in conflict, since both HKCU tried to load this add-in and HKLM tried to load this add-in and as a result it didn't allow Outlook Add-In to load at all. As soon as I've got only the HKCU registry setting, my add-in loaded normally. =D

Answer (score 0):

This also happens if you have the InstallAllUsersVisible flag = FALSE in the UI Interface if using an MSI package. Setting it back to the default TRUE fixed this error for me. I had it working using HKCU - but Victor F nailed the source of the issue.